# Use curved lines in bumps chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, spline

I'm trying to make a bumps chart (like [parallel coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates) but with an ordinal x-axis) to show ranking over time. I can make a straight-line chart very easily:

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(47)

df <- as.data.frame(as.table(replicate(8, sample(4))), responseName = 'rank')
df$Var2 <- as.integer(df$Var2)

head(df)
#>   Var1 Var2 rank
#> 1    A    1    4
#> 2    B    1    2
#> 3    C    1    3
#> 4    D    1    1
#> 5    A    2    3
#> 6    B    2    4

ggplot(df, aes(Var2, rank, color = Var1)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Wonderful. Now, though, I want to make the connecting lines curved. Despite never having more than one y per x, `geom_smooth` offers some possibilities. `loess` seems like it should work, as it can ignore points except the closest. However, even with tweaking the best I can get still misses lots of points and overshoots others where it should be flat:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Var2, rank, color = Var1)) + 
    geom_smooth(method = 'loess', span = .7, se = FALSE) + 
    geom_point()
```

[image]

I've tried a number of other splines, like `ggalt::geom_xspline`, but they all still overshoot or miss the points:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Var2, rank, color = Var1)) + ggalt::geom_xspline() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Is there an easy way to curve these lines? Do I need to build my own sigmoidal spline? To clarify, I'm looking for something like [D3.js's `d3.curveMonotoneX`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#curveMonotoneX) which hits every point and whose local maxima and minima do not exceed the y values:

[image: d3.curveMonotoneX image]

Ideally it would probably have a slope of 0 at each point, too, but that's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: As per [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29442) -- what about the `cobs` package? "COBS stands for Constrained B-splines. Possible constraints include going through specific points, setting derivatives to specified values, monotonicity (increasing or decreasing), concavity, convexity, periodicity, etc." I can't immediately get it to work but there's promise.

Comment: Ooh, that looks promising. I was trying `fda::smooth.monotone`, but it's parameters are ridiculously complex.

Comment: i think you can do this with loess by tweaking the degree and span `geom_smooth(method = 'loess', span = 0.3, se = FALSE,                 method.args=list(degree=1))`

Comment: @user2957945 Interesting, that works! It does spew a lot of warnings, though, and even tweaking the span further, it still fails on my real data, which is a little bigger.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using `signal::pchip` with a grid of X-values works, at least in your example with numeric axes. A proper `geom_` would be nice, but hey...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(signal)
set.seed(47)

df <- as.data.frame(as.table(replicate(8, sample(4))), responseName = 'rank')
df$Var2 <- as.integer(df$Var2)

head(df)
#>   Var1 Var2 rank
#> 1    A    1    4
#> 2    B    1    2
#> 3    C    1    3
#> 4    D    1    1
#> 5    A    2    3
#> 6    B    2    4

ggplot(df, aes(Var2, rank, color = Var1)) +
  geom_line(data = df %>%
              group_by(Var1) %>%
              do({
                tibble(Var2 = seq(min(.$Var2), max(.$Var2),length.out=100),
                       rank = pchip(.$Var2, .$rank, Var2))
              })) +
  geom_point()
```

Result: [image: Result]

Comment: Beautiful! I've got to say, I think this is the best first answer I've ever seen. With some slight trickery, you can hack it all into ggplot, too: `ggplot(df, aes(Var2, rank, color = Var1)) + geom_point() + lapply(split(df, df$Var1), function(.data){stat_function(aes(color = Var1), .data, fun = function(x){signal::pchip(.data$Var2, .data$rank, x)})})`

Answer (score 2):

Building on Henrik's answer, this wraps up `pchip` (I'm using the one from `pracma` here but the result is the same) so it can be used alongside existing smooth methods more easily:

```
ggpchip = function(formula, data, weights) structure(pracma::pchipfun(data$x, data$y), class='ggpchip')
predict.ggpchip = function(object, newdata, se.fit=F, ...) {
  fit = unclass(object)(newdata$x)
  if (se.fit) list(fit=data.frame(fit, lwr=fit, upr=fit), se.fit=fit * 0) else fit
}
```

Then the actual ggplot call is straightforward:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Var2, rank, color=Var1)) + geom_smooth(method='ggpchip', se=F) + geom_point()
```

You can then use pchip to smooth other geoms, eg area plots:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Var2, rank, fill=Var1)) + stat_smooth(method='ggpchip', geom='area', position='fill')
```