# Using stat_smooth with geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking to produce a linegraph with 3-7 lines using stat_smooth to produce a smooth curve then rather than one which changes at every data point.

This is my script for the plot currently:

```
Data_Arr %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=Period, y=M_Min, colour = Day_Week)) + 
geom_line(aes(group=`Day Name`)) +
geom_hline(aes(yintercept= 120, linetype = "120MPM"), colour= 'lawngreen')+
ylim(0,200)+
stat_smooth(aes(x=Period, y=M_Min, colour = Day_Week))+
theme_readable()
```

And this what it produces:
[image: Current plot]

Stat_smooth appears to be working for some of it but not all? I haven't used stat_smooth before so this is probably a simple fix I'm missing

This is the dataset

```
Data_Arr = structure(list(Season = c(1718, 1718, 1718, 1718, 1718, 1718, 
1718, 1718, 1718, 1718), Week = c("Wk 40 Newcastle_H", "Wk 40 Newcastle_H", 
"Wk 40 Newcastle_H", "Wk 41 Wasps_A", "Wk 41 Wasps_A", "Wk 41 Wasps_A", 
"Wk 42 No_Game", "Wk 40 Newcastle_H", "Wk 40 Newcastle_H", "Wk 40 
Newcastle_H"
), Day_Week = c("Wk 40 Newcastle_H Attack_3G", "Wk 40 Newcastle_H 
Defence_3G", 
"Wk 40 Newcastle_H Newcastle_H", "Wk 41 Wasps_A Defence_3G", 
"Wk 41 Wasps_A Attack_3G", "Wk 41 Wasps_A Wasps_A", "Wk 42 No_Game 
Rugby_Games", 
"Wk 40 Newcastle_H Attack_3G", "Wk 40 Newcastle_H Defence_3G", 
"Wk 40 Newcastle_H Newcastle_H"), Date = structure(c(1522886400, 
1522713600, 1523059200, 1523318400, 1523491200, 1523664000, 1523923200, 
1522886400, 1522713600, 1523059200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Day = c("Thu", "Tue", "Sat", "Tue", "Thu", 
"Sat", "Tue", "Thu", "Tue", "Sat"), `Training/Match` = c("Training", 
"Training", "Match_P", "Training", "Training", "Match_P", "Training", 
"Training", "Training", "Match_P"), `Day Name` = c("Attack_3G", 
"Defence_3G", "Newcastle_H", "Defence_3G", "Attack_3G", "Wasps_A", 
"Rugby_Games", "Attack_3G", "Defence_3G", "Newcastle_H"), `Full 
Match/Training/Quarters` = c("Training", 
"Training", "Match_P", "Training", "Training", "Match_P", "Training", 
"Training", "Training", "Match_P"), `Squad Classification` = c("Senior", 
"Senior", "Senior", "Senior", "Senior", "Senior", "Senior", "Senior", 
"Senior", "Senior"), `Forward/Back` = c("Backs", "Backs", "Backs", 
"Backs", "Backs", "Backs", "Backs", "Backs", "Backs", "Backs"
), Position = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L), .Label = c("Prop", "Hooker", "Second Row", "Back Row", "Scrum Half", 
"Fly Half", "Centre", "Wing/FullBack"), class = "factor"), Player.Name = 
c("Arr Jonny", 
"Arr Jonny", "Arr Jonny", "Arr Jonny", "Arr Jonny", "Arr Jonny", 
"Arr Jonny", "Arr Jonny", "Arr Jonny", "Arr Jonny"), Period = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Min_1", "Min_2", 
"Min_3", "Min_4", "Min_5", "Min_6", "Min_7", "Min_8", "Min_9", 
"Min_10"), class = "factor"), M_Min = c(154.3, 188, 156.2687833, 
175.9911, 159.422783333333, 137.872366666667, 153.349133333333, 
150.6, 166, 139.1597833)), .Names = c("Season", "Week", "Day_Week", 
"Date", "Day", "Training/Match", "Day Name", "Full Match/Training/Quarters", 
"Squad Classification", "Forward/Back", "Position", "Player.Name", 
"Period", "M_Min"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thanks

EDIT: This is the type of plot I'm looking to produce but this one was produced in excel and I'm looking to do it in R

[image: Sample]

Comment: You have only two timepoints in your dataset. Thus I do not see the point of using stat_smooth ? Maybe this post might interest you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771900/use-curved-lines-in-bumps-chart

Comment: `data.frame(x=runif(100),y=rnorm(100)) %>% ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm") ` 
Does you desired output resemble something like produced by the code above?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I added an example of the type of plot I am trying to produce. I can format the plot to be similar but its the line smoothing I an stuck on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question here's my proposition : group data based on Period and Day_week and produce the mean M_min. Then plot using ggplot geom_line() :

```
Data_Arr %>% 
   group_by(Period,Day_Week) %>% 
   summarise(mean_M_Min=mean(M_Min)) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x=Period,y=mean_M_Min,colour=Day_Week,group=Day_Week)) + 
   geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to change it to this to produce a plot `Data_Arr %>% 
  group_by(Period,Day_Week) %>% 
  summarise(mean_M_Min=mean(M_Min)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Period,y=mean_M_Min,colour=Day_Week, group=1)) + 
  geom_line()` but the plot produced had very jagged lines still.

Comment: change `group=1` by `group=Day_Week`